# Specified Cast is not Valid in new Master Screen of Acumatica ERP System

Tags: c#, acumatica

I already create new additional master screen (ListView) in Acumatica.
The following code is the source code of the page :

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPages/ListView.master" AutoEventWireup="true" ValidateRequest="false" CodeFile="CS213000.aspx.cs" Inherits="Page__213000" Title="Untitled Page" %>
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/MasterPages/ListView.master" %>
<asp:Content ID="cont1" ContentPlaceHolderID="phDS" runat="Server">
<px:PXDataSource ID="ds" runat="server" Visible="True" PrimaryView="RoomMaster" SuspendUnloading="False" TypeName="SGLCustomizeProject.RoomMaint" >
</px:PXDataSource>
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="cont2" ContentPlaceHolderID="phL" runat="Server">
<px:PXGrid ID="grid" runat="server" Height="400px" Width="100%" Style="z-index: 100"
    AllowPaging="True" AllowSearch="True" AdjustPageSize="Auto" DataSourceID="ds" SkinID="Inquire" TabIndex="900" 
    AllowAdd="True" TemporaryFilterCaption="Filter Applied">
<Levels>
<px:PXGridLevel DataMember="RoomMaster">
<Columns>
<px:PXGridColumn DataField="BranchID" Width="120px">
                </px:PXGridColumn>
                <px:PXGridColumn DataField="BuildingID">
                </px:PXGridColumn>
                <px:PXGridColumn DataField="RoomCD" Width="200px">
                </px:PXGridColumn>
                <px:PXGridColumn DataField="RoomDescription" Width="200px">
                </px:PXGridColumn>
                <px:PXGridColumn DataField="Status">
                </px:PXGridColumn>
</Columns>
        </px:PXGridLevel>
    </Levels>
<AutoSize Container="Window" Enabled="True" MinHeight="200" />
</px:PXGrid>
```

The following code is the source code of PXGraph :

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using PX.SM;
using PX.Data;
namespace SGLCustomizeProject
{
    public class RoomMaint : PXGraph<RoomMaint>
    {
        public PXCancel<RoomMaster> Cancel;
        public PXSave<RoomMaster> Save;
        public PXInsert<RoomMaster> Insert;
        public PXSelect<RoomMaster> RoomMaster;
    }
}
```

The following code is the source code of DAC :

```
namespace SGLCustomizeProject
{
using System;
using PX.Data;
using PX.Objects.GL;
using PX.Objects.AR;
using PX.Objects.CR;
using PX.Objects.FA;

[System.SerializableAttribute()]
public class RoomMaster : PX.Data.IBqlTable
{
    #region BranchID
    public abstract class branchID : PX.Data.IBqlField
    {
    }
    protected Int32? _BranchID;
    [PXDBInt(IsKey = true)]
    [PXDefault()]
    //[PXUIField(DisplayName = "BranchID")]
    [Branch()]
    public virtual Int32? BranchID
    {
        get
        {
            return this._BranchID;
        }
        set
        {
            this._BranchID = value;
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region BuildingID
    public abstract class buildingID : PX.Data.IBqlField
    {
    }
    protected Int32? _BuildingID;
    [PXDBInt()]
    [PXDefault()]
    [PXSelector(typeof(Search<Building.buildingID, 
                        Where<Building.branchID, 
                         Equal<Current<FALocationHistory.locationID>>>>),
        SubstituteKey = typeof(Building.buildingCD), DescriptionField = typeof(Building.description))]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Building")]
    public virtual Int32? BuildingID
    {
        get
        {
            return this._BuildingID;
        }
        set
        {
            this._BuildingID = value;
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region RoomCD
    public abstract class roomCD : PX.Data.IBqlField
    {
    }
    protected string _RoomCD;
    [PXDBString(50, IsUnicode = true, IsKey = true)]
    [PXDefault()]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Kode Area")]
    public virtual string RoomCD
    {
        get
        {
            return this._RoomCD;
        }
        set
        {
            this._RoomCD = value;
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region RoomID
    public abstract class roomID : PX.Data.IBqlField
    {
    }
    protected int? _RoomID;
    [PXDBIdentity()]
    [PXUIField(Enabled = false)]
    public virtual int? RoomID
    {
        get
        {
            return this._RoomID;
        }
        set
        {
            this._RoomID = value;
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region RoomDescription
    public abstract class roomDescription : PX.Data.IBqlField
    {
    }
    protected string _RoomDescription;
    [PXDBString(75, IsUnicode = true)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Deskripsi Area")]
    public virtual string RoomDescription
    {
        get
        {
            return this._RoomDescription;
        }
        set
        {
            this._RoomDescription = value;
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Status
    public abstract class status : PX.Data.IBqlField
    {
    }
    protected string _Status;
    [PXDBString(2, IsFixed = true)]
    [PXDefault()]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Status")]
    [PXStringList(new string[]
        {
            "01",
            "02"
        },

        new string[]
        {
            "Active",
            "Inactive"
        })]
    public virtual string Status
    {
        get
        {
            return this._Status;
        }
        set
        {
            this._Status = value;
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region tstamp
    public abstract class Tstamp : PX.Data.IBqlField
    {
    }
    protected byte[] _tstamp;
    [PXDBTimestamp()]
    public virtual byte[] tstamp
    {
        get
        {
            return this._tstamp;
        }
        set
        {
            this._tstamp = value;
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region CreatedByID
    public abstract class createdByID : PX.Data.IBqlField
    {
    }
    protected Guid? _CreatedByID;
    //[PXDBField()]
    //[PXDefault()]
    //[PXUIField(DisplayName = "CreatedByID")]
    [PXDBCreatedByID]
    public virtual Guid? CreatedByID
    {
        get
        {
            return this._CreatedByID;
        }
        set
        {
            this._CreatedByID = value;
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region CreatedByScreenID
    public abstract class createdByScreenID : PX.Data.IBqlField
    {
    }
    protected string _CreatedByScreenID;
    //[PXDBString(8, IsFixed = true)]
    //[PXDefault("")]
    //[PXUIField(DisplayName = "CreatedByScreenID")]
    [PXDBCreatedByScreenID]
    public virtual string CreatedByScreenID
    {
        get
        {
            return this._CreatedByScreenID;
        }
        set
        {
            this._CreatedByScreenID = value;
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region CreatedDateTime
    public abstract class createdDateTime : PX.Data.IBqlField
    {
    }
    protected DateTime? _CreatedDateTime;
    //[PXDBDate()]
    //[PXDefault(TypeCode.DateTime, "01/01/1900")]
    //[PXUIField(DisplayName = "CreatedDateTime")]
    [PXDBCreatedDateTime]
    public virtual DateTime? CreatedDateTime
    {
        get
        {
            return this._CreatedDateTime;
        }
        set
        {
            this._CreatedDateTime = value;
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region LastModifiedByID
    public abstract class lastModifiedByID : PX.Data.IBqlField
    {
    }
    protected Guid? _LastModifiedByID;
    //[PXDBField()]
    //[PXDefault()]
    //[PXUIField(DisplayName = "LastModifiedByID")]
    [PXDBLastModifiedByID]
    public virtual Guid? LastModifiedByID
    {
        get
        {
            return this._LastModifiedByID;
        }
        set
        {
            this._LastModifiedByID = value;
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region LastModifiedDateTime
    public abstract class lastModifiedDateTime : PX.Data.IBqlField
    {
    }
    protected DateTime? _LastModifiedDateTime;
    //[PXDBDate()]
    //[PXDefault(TypeCode.DateTime, "01/01/1900")]
    //[PXUIField(DisplayName = "LastModifiedDateTime")]
    [PXDBLastModifiedDateTime]
    public virtual DateTime? LastModifiedDateTime
    {
        get
        {
            return this._LastModifiedDateTime;
        }
        set
        {
            this._LastModifiedDateTime = value;
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
}
```

When I tried to add new record for the first time is doesn't matter, but when I tried to add another record or open the screen, I got the following error message :

[image]

Does anyone know how to solve this case ?
Thanks

Comment: you should include the trace details from the trace window. Might help to point to an event that is running that could help answer the question. Could be the ID/CD setup on this field. My thought you might need to add the RowTemplate in aspx inside the PXGrid tags for the building field. Ex: <RowTemplate>
                    <px:PXSelector ID="edBuildingID" runat="server" DataField="BuildingID"/>
                </RowTemplate>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PXSelector on BuildingID field shows a WHERE clause limiting results to         Current FALocationHistory.locationID but I don't see FALocationHistory in the context of the RoomMaint  graph. Did you intend to limit the list based on the choice of BranchID in this new RoomMaster row? If true, then you will also need CommitChanges=true on the BranchID column and also AutoRefresh=true on the BuildingID px:PXSelector control in a RowTemplate section of the gridlevel, such as:

```
<RowTemplate>

<px:PXSelector ID="edBuildingID" runat="server" DataField="BuildingID" 
                    DataSourceID="ds" AutoRefresh="True">

</RowTemplate>
```

You may need to add SyncPosition=true on the Grid tag of the markup in this case.  Also try placing the IsKey=true only on the RoomID identity field instead of BranchID/RoomCD.