# Value of new customize field in Acumatica ERP doesn't save to database

Tags: c#, acumatica

I already created new additional custom field in screen FA303000 (Fixed Asset).
I used the following code to create this custom field:

DAC Extension

```
using PX.Data;
using PX.Objects.CR;
using PX.Objects.CS;
using PX.Objects.EP;
using PX.Objects.FA;
using PX.Objects.GL;
using PX.Objects;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;

namespace SGLCustomizeProject
{
    public class FALocationHistoryExtension : PXCacheExtension<PX.Objects.FA.FALocationHistory>
    {
        #region UsrKodeArea
        [PXString]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Kode Area")]
        [PXSelector(typeof(Search<KodeAreaMaster.roomCD, Where<KodeAreaMaster.status, Equal<statusActive>>>),
                typeof(KodeAreaMaster.roomCD), 
                typeof(KodeAreaMaster.roomDescription), 
                typeof(KodeAreaMaster.status))]
        public virtual string UsrKodeArea { get; set; }
        public abstract class usrKodeArea : IBqlField { }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

And the following screenshot is the layout after customized.
[image]

The first problem is after transaction saved, the value of new custom field does not saved to database.
[image]

[image]

The second problem is how to filtering selector field based on another field in the current screen. for example from this case is I need to filtering Kode Area based on Current Building ?

[image]

[image]

I already set the properties of field UsrKodeArea & UsrDeskripsiArea like the following screenshot:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your custom field is using [PXString], try changing to [PXDBString] to have bound to the database.  For the dependent dropdown of Building and KodeArea, CommitChanges=true should exist on the BuildingID PXSelector tag in the aspx markup, something like:

```
 <px:PXSelector ID="edBuildingID" runat="server" DataField="BuildingID" CommitChanges="true" DisplayMode="Text" />
```

Ensure your KodeArea selector has the AutoRefresh=true, similar to answer here for Branch/Building [assuming those were dependent dropdowns]: 
[Specified Cast is not Valid in new Master Screen of Acumatica ERP System](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57519737/specified-cast-is-not-valid-in-new-master-screen-of-acumatica-erp-system/57523919?noredirect=1#comment101632172_57523919)

Importantly, the KodeArea PXSelector in code should be limited to the Current<>  choice of BuildingID, such as:

```
  [PXSelector(typeof(Search<KodeAreaMaster.roomCD, 
Where<KodeAreaMaster.status, Equal<statusActive>, 
    And<KodeAreaMaster.buildingID, 
        Equal<Current<FALocationHistory.buildingID>>>>>),
            typeof(KodeAreaMaster.roomCD), 
            typeof(KodeAreaMaster.roomDescription), 
            typeof(KodeAreaMaster.status))]
```

Comment: Thanks for your respons, I have tried your suggestion, it works if I have to save the current fixed asset with selected buildingID first. And then I can select KodeArea based on current BuildingID. Is it possible to filter KodeArea field based on any selected BuildingID, not only based on Current BuildingID event not saved yet ?

Comment: Is AutoRefresh=true present on the KodeArea  px:PXSelector tag in the markup?  Does the listing of KodeArea options (KodeAreaMaster.roomCD) change upon change of BuildingID chosen? When a new BuildingID is chosen, also include in your code a FALocationHistory_BuildingID_FieldUpdated event handler to set the KodeAreaMaster.roomCD = null to prevent BuildingID/RoomCD mismatch.  The event handler may need a delegate in the method signature to invoke any underlying event from the AssetMaint graph.

Comment: I've set the AutoRefresh=true for the KodeArea pxselector field, please see my updated question above. About the FALocationHistory_BuildingID_FieldUpdated event handler, could you please show the sample of  the code ? Thanks.

Comment: The event would look something like:

    public virtual void FALocationHistory_BuildingID_FieldUpdated(PXCache cache, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        FALocationHistory row = (FALocationHistory)e.Row;
        if (row != null)
        {
            // reset
            row.usrRoomCD = null;
        }
    }

Comment: With the event, add a breakpoint and debug to ensure the BuildingID is indeed changing.  If still an issue, review the AssetMaint graph code 
(App_Data >> Code Repository >> PX.Objects >> FA folder) to learn what may be affecting behavior.

Comment: thanks for your comments, I already implements your suggestion and it works, Thanks :)